# Rotating an array - error

Tags: c++

The task is, given an array of ints and an integer K, shift the elements of the array by K. That is, given A = [3 8 9 7 6], the output should be [9 7 6 3 8]. The output also needs to be a vector.

Below is my code, but it produces a seg fault! What went wrong?

```
vector<int> solution(vector<int> &A, int K) {
    int sizeA = A.size();
    vector<int> B;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
        B[i] = A[(i+K) % sizeA];
    }
    return B;
}
```

---

Thanks to the comments and answers, the correct code is

```
vector<int> solution(vector<int> &A, int K) {
    int sizeA = A.size();
    vector<int> B(sizeA);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
        B[(i+K) % sizeA] = A[i];
    }
    return B;
}
```

Comment: You use vector B as if its size is == A.Size() instead - it is 0. Create B as `vector<int> B(sizeA)`

Comment: There is a [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) that does this job for you.

Comment: [See this example of std::rotate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f512ae1a919f8b0)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to index into `B`, but it's just default constructed, so its size is 0 and indexing any element gives undefined behavior. You can construct it at the right size, or resize() it to get the right size, or just use push_back to push the items into it in the correct order. Or you use `std::rotate` to rotate the original one in place.

Comment: Thank you, interestingly it seems I also need to change the assignment line to B[(i+K) % sizeA] = A[i]; (not totally clear why at this point)

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use **vector(size_type n)** to construct the **B**

```
vector<int> solution(vector<int> &A, int K) {
    int sizeA = A.size();
    //make a B of sizeA elements
    vector<int> B(sizeA);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
        B[i] = A[(i+K) % sizeA];
    }
    return B;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

B has not initialized yet so indexing it would give you an error.

Instead of using:

```
B[i] = A[(i+K) % sizeA];
```

use:

```
B.push_back(A[(i+K) % sizeA]);
```